# Sessions vanishing when doing a header redirect with php

Tags: php, session

Only impacts Internet Explorer and Firefox (works in chrome and opera).

When I try to do a header redirect the session is dropped.  For an example I wrote the small bit of code below as a test...

```
Page1 (test.php)
<?php 
session_start(); 
$_SESSION['testvar']=true;
session_write_close();
//header('Location: ./test2.php'); 
$host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$uri = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/\\');
$extra = 'test2.php';
header("Location: http://$host$uri/$extra");
exit;
//header('Location: http://' .$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].":".$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'].     '/test2.php');
//header('Location: http://192.168.1.111:78/test2.php');
?>

Page2 (test2.php)
<?php
session_start(); 
echo $_SESSION['testvar'];
echo "<br>test Page #2 (You should see a 1 above if it worked!)<br><br>";
?>
```

I have literally tried absolutely everything I can think of (and or google).

Comment: What is the original URL from which your redirecting away? How do you set your session ID? Cookie or URL parameter?

Comment: Because i'm testing on the internal network the first address is http://192.168.1.111:78/test.php.  I don't set the session ID, I've tried to manually set it to no avail.

Comment: Are you using cookies or URL parameters (or both)? You need to look that up in your PHP configuration.

Comment: I'm a bit of a novice when it comes to the php config file.  I know it's location but what specifically would I be looking for?

Comment: You need to look into that file for session configuration, a list of all configuration can be found here: http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php - don't get overwhelmed from the sheer number of settings :), just some apply. Next to that within in the php.ini you find useful comments next to each setting.

Comment: Thanks for all of your help.  It was just set to only allow cookies.  I updated it to allow both (I think) but it is still not working.  I pasted it here if that helps... [PHP.INI](http://pastebin.com/4758YASJ)

Comment: If you allow both now, you can try to add the session id as a query parameter to the redirect URL: `header("Location: http://$host$uri/$extra?".SID);`. If that solves your issue, you're one step ahead.

Comment: That worked!  I'll apply this across the code that was giving me the real problem and see if it fixed it.  You're a lifesaver!

Comment: Well wait, if you can solve the cookie problem, you won't need to change the code. The `SID` test showed that the problem is transporting the session id which normally works with cookies. Check the cookie path of the session cookie. Maybe the port setting is irritating firefox and internet explorer and you need to specify it.

Comment: The cookie stuff confuses the hell out of me to be honest.  I don't want to impose on you because you've been so helpful but how would I go about checking the cookie path and port setting?

Comment: Each cookie specifies to which domain it applies to. That value can be specified and should match your server+port or only server, I would experiment a bit, it's late and I do not exactly know: http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-domain

Answer (score 0):

First As other guys told, you have to check php.ini file for the dir that stores the session handlers
 there is fragment from php.ini file that shows what to do:

```
Handler used to store/retrieve data.
session.save_handler = files

; Argument passed to save_handler.  In the case of files, this is the path
; where data files are stored. Note: Windows users have to change this
; variable in order to use PHP's session functions.
;
; As of PHP 4.0.1, you can define the path as:
;
;     session.save_path = "N;/path"
;
; where N is an integer.  Instead of storing all the session files in
; /path, what this will do is use subdirectories N-levels deep, and
; store the session data in those directories.  This is useful if you
; or your OS have problems with lots of files in one directory, and is
; a more efficient layout for servers that handle lots of sessions.
;
; NOTE 1: PHP will not create this directory structure automatically.
;         You can use the script in the ext/session dir for that purpose.
; NOTE 2: See the section on garbage collection below if you choose to
;         use subdirectories for session storage
;
; The file storage module creates files using mode 600 by default.
; You can change that by using
;
;     session.save_path = "N;MODE;/path"
;
; where MODE is the octal representation of the mode. Note that this
; does not overwrite the process's umask.
session.save_path = "/tmp"
```

Note that this folder has to be created manualy with the appropriate permissions.